# Double Calculator in C

Tags: c

I have a very simple doubles calculator written in C. It is so simple, a 5 year old could have made it. However, I am stuck on the numbers it returns toward the end. With the doubles variable at type long, the script runs, but in the middle, the script prints "4611686018427387904", then "-9223372036854775808", then 0 until the for loop stops repeating.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long doubles = 1;
    int counter;
    for(counter = 1; counter < 200; counter++) {
        doubles = doubles * 2;
        printf("%li\n", doubles);
    }
return 7;
}
```

If you change the type of doubles to int (and change the argument type in the print statement), then the code returns the correct numbers, but then prints "1073741824", then "-2147483648", then 0 until the loop runs out.

If you change the type of doubles to float and change the argument type, the code prints correctly, then "170141183460469231731687303715884105728.000000", then "inf" for the rest of the loop.

Why does this do that? My guess is that you can only fit numbers of x length in y bytes (4 for int, 8 for long) do to the limits of binary. 32 1's and 0's fit into 4 bytes, and 64 1's and 0's fit into 8 bytes. The flaw in that theory is that int variables and float variables have the same byte-count, as proven in the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int integer;
    long longVariable;
    float floatingPoint;
    printf("Size of int: %lu bytes\nSize of long: %lu bytes\nSize of float: %lu bytes\n", sizeof(integer), sizeof(longVariable), sizeof(floatingPoint));
    return 7;
}
```

This code prints:

Size of int: **4 bytes**

Size of long: 8 bytes

Size of float: **4 bytes**

That renders my previous theory invalid, because, in my theory, a float shouldn't be able to count higher than an int if the binary space allotted was the same. What in the world is going on?!

Comment: overflow.. overflow..

Comment: “That renders my previous theory invalid, because, in my theory, a float shouldn't be able to count higher than an int if the binary space allotted was the same.” Surely if two different formats have been defined with different names, it was for the purpose of representing different sets of numbers, no?

Comment: Your code needs 200 Bits. Floats and ints are the same size but a float is in 2 parts. X^y so a larger range but less precision

Comment: Minor question for OP: Why did you use the `"%lu"` format specifier when printing `sizeof()`, versus using `"%u"`, `"%zu"`, or anything else?

Comment: chux, I used a long unsigned int because clang gave a warning when I tried to use %i, and a suggestion on how to fix it. Long story short, clang said use %lu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A float/double isn´t built like an integer type.
int´s are straight-forward binary numbers, maybe with a sign.
A floating point variable has a third part, an exponent, so that the effective value is

```
+/- mantisse ^ exponent
```

(with ^ is math. "power", not binary "xor").

Large numbers won´t be saved exactly if they are not powers of 2
(like 10000000000000000000000 and 10000000000000000000001
won´t make a difference in float, it will be 1000000...something)
because there is only limited space for the actual value.
But it can vaguely represent such large numbers with it´s exponent.

Problem is, a conversion to int want to make an exact value of it,
and that won´t fit in 4 byte.